# problems with finding checkboxlist ID with findcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

can anyone help me with the following problem?:
Im creating a checkboxlist control dynamically for each item in my list with categories. Im placing each checkboxlist on the related div.

```
CheckBoxList cblist = new CheckBoxList();

foreach (Category cat in Data.Instance.Listcategorys())
         {      
              if (category.TypeID == parameterid)
            {
                 ListItem item = new ListItem(category.Name, category.ID.ToString());
                 cblist.ID = "cblist" + parameterid;
                 divRowHeader.Controls.Add(cblist );
                 cblist.Items.Add(item);
             } 
        }
```

each cheackboxlist contains his own items based in the "parameterid".

i have to check which items are checked, so made i foreach loop to find the control:

```
foreach (Control c in div.Controls)
        {
            CheckBoxList cblfound = (((CheckBoxList)c.FindControl("???")));

            foreach (ListItem item in cblfound Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {}

       }
```

the problem is here. .Net creates his own ID's for each Checkboxlist. How can i make it possible to find the control with .findcontrol? im using .net 3.5

thanks in advance

Comment: Why you are not using `linq`?

Comment: To do what? adding the checkboxlistID's in a listsession or something?

Comment: FindControl, according to MSDN, is intended to find a control whose ID is not known at design time. You are creating the control yourself and populating it, so you should "know" what control you are looking for when you want to see what was checked. I think there is a disconnect in your design or thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could rethink your approach using [IEnumerable.OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and some additional linq, like so:

```
var selectedControls = div.Controls.OfType(CheckBoxList).Where(item => item.Selected);

foreach(CheckBoxList item in selectedControls)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: var selectedControls = new List<CheckBoxList>();
        foreach (Control contr in div.Controls)
        {
            selectedControls.AddRange(contr.Controls.OfType<CheckBoxList>());
        }
        foreach (CheckBoxList itemlist in selectedControls)
        {}   
Solved my problem. thanks for the linq solution